# Searching for a word in cstring text (1-D array/c++)

Tags: c++, arrays, search, cpu-word, c-strings

I'm practicing 1-D array and the question asks from the user to input a line of text and then input a word that the user wants to search and find out how many times it's repeated in the line of text. It doesn't have to be a separated by spaces and can be in a word (i.e. 'go' in 'goalkeeper').

My problem is creating a proper *if condition* in the loop that searches through the sentence. Thing is, my line variable is *char* ( `char line[200];` ) while my word variable was *string* (`string word;`) so my program gave me an error when I wrote a condition in the loop that went like this:

```
if ( line[i] == word)
```

Then I tried changing the word variable to *char* and created a loop to get the input but then I got stuck with how to work out the loop that searches through the line of text.

I just want some pointers. This is my current code so far (it's a mess):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
int main()

{
    char liner[200], word[200];
    int i, counter1 = 0, counter2 = 0;


    cout<<"Enter a line of text: ";
    cin.get (liner, 200);

    cout<<"Enter a word to search: ";

    for (i = 0; word[i] != ' '; i++)
    {
        cin>>word[i];

    }

    cout<<endl;

    for (i = 0; i < 200; i++)
    {
        if (liner[i] == word[t])
            {
                counter2++;
            }

    }

    cout<<word<<" was found "<<counter2<<" times."<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use strncmp, which compares 2 strings up to the specified length to see if they are equal (stopping when end of either is reached or number of chars have been compared).

So, the code would be something like:

```
int main()
{
    char liner[200], word[200];
    int i, counter1 = 0, counter2 = 0;

    cout<<"Enter a line of text: ";
    cin.getline(liner, 200);

    cout<<"Enter a word to search: ";
    cin.getline(word, 200);
    cout<<endl;

    int lineLen = strlen(line);
    int wordLen = strlen(word);

    for (i = 0; i < lineLen && I < wordLen; i++)
    {
        if (strncmp(&line[i], word, wordLen)
        {
           counter2++;
        }
    }

    cout<<word<<" was found "<<counter2<<" times."<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

To improve the program, you can try not using a fixed size array, but read the data into a std::string.

Comment: @Deduplicator you should post that as an answer, because it is correct.